# How to create desktop shortcut in xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, shortcut-file, netbeans-9

I have xubuntu 18.04 installed. I have just downloaded netbeans-9.0 binary zip from apache site. and extracted in home directory as netbeans-9.0.

I can run this application by ~/netbeans-9.0/bin/netbeans.

But I want to add desktop shortcut in xubuntu start menu.

What are the ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

First create a netbeans-9.0.desktop file in any directory.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=NetBeans IDE 9.0
Comment=The Smarter Way to Code
Exec=/bin/sh "/home/USER/netbeans-9.0/bin/netbeans"
Icon=/home/USER/netbeans-9.0/nb/netbeans.png
Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0
```

Then move this file to `/home/USER/.local/share/applications` directory.

You will see the icon in start menu on searching.

Comment: It is also possible to put the file in `/usr/share/applications`. Then, the entry in the start menu will be available for all users.

Answer (score 1):

Go on Desktop -> Right Click -> Create Launcher

[image]

For Command pick: "/home/USER/netbeans-9.0/bin/netbeans"

For Icon press "No Icon" button

[image]

and from "Select icon from:" pick "Image Files"

[image]

and then select "/home/USER/netbeans-9.0/nb/netbeans.png"

or

"/home/USER/netbeans-9.0/nb/**netbeans.icns**"